# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toggleToStart' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, richfaces, prototypejs

I have a `<rich:simpleTogglePanel>`. On click of this panel am getting 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toggleToStart' of undefined` in console.

Screen shot has been attached.

In my xhtml page, I have [prototype.js](http://prototypejs.org/download/) to show a lightbox. If I remove prototype.js
the above TypeError is not thrown and toggle panel works fine. But, my lightbox won't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scriptaculous.js?load=effects"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lightwindow.js"></script>

<a href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/pages/lightBoxPage.jsf?popupcat=#{someList.category}"
   class="lightwindow page-options" params="lightwindow_type=external,lightwindow_width=845,lightwindow_height=350"
   caption=" " title="">
  click here
</a>

<h:panelGrid columns="1">
  <rich:dataTable var="myList" value="#{bean.someList}" id="dataGrid">
     <rich:column>
       <rich:simpleTogglePanel switchType="client" opened="#{!myList.expandedList}"
         onexpand="return setSelectedGenre(#{myList.category});"
         oncollapse="return setSelectedGenre(#{myList.category});"
         headerClass="bluebg1" style="border-color:#FFFFFF" >

          //Display items inside toggle panel

       </rich:simpleTogglePanel>
     </rich:column>
  </rich:dataTable>
</h:panelGrid>
```

My guess is "toggle" is in conflict with prototype.js and `rich:simpleTogglePanel`.

Rich Faces version is 3.3.3

How to fix this?
[image]

Comment: Than use a jQuery based lightbox, there are plenty of them. And if you are mixing jQuery and prototypejs, you need to make sure that jQuery is running in no conflict mode since they both use $.

Comment: Since prototypejs doesn't have no conflict mode, I should do that in jQuery. But, am using simpleTogglePanel which (behind the scenes) could be using jQuery. Am not sure how to configure no conflict mode for simpleTogglePanel.

Comment: If the plugin is written the correct way, it should have no issues. If they wrote it the wrong way, there is nothing you can do.